# How to prove uniqueness of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

How to prove that there is exactly one probability measure
$\nu$ on $($ $\mathbb{(R^+)}^2$, ($\mathcal B\mathbb({\mathbb{R^+}})^2 $)$)$ such that $\forall a,b\in [0, \infty[$:

$\nu(]a, \infty[\times ]b, \infty[)\ = \ e^{-(a+b)^5}$

As of now the only think that seems logical to me is to use Carathéodory's extension theorem, but I dont know how to go about it and satisfy the 6 assumptions of that theorem. Meaning that my starting point may be right but I'm not getting anywhere.

Can anyone help me showing how to use the theorem and satisfy the assumptions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Too many questions of the same type have been appearing in the last 24 hours. (In the other questions they had $e^{-(a+b)^{3}}$) Where are these coming from ?

Comment: Use the monotone class theorem (or the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Your measure is probably absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Let us assume that there is a $f : {\bf R}^2 \rightarrow {\bf R}_+$ such that $$\nu(A) = \int\int_A f(x,y)dxdy.$$

Then we have $$\nu(]a,\infty[\times ]b,\infty[) = \int_b^\infty \int_a^\infty f(x,y) dxdy = e^{-(a+b)^5}.$$

We can differentiate with respect to $a$ then to $b$ which gives
$$f(a,b) = {\partial \over \partial b}{\partial \over \partial a} e^{-(a+b)^5}.$$
Once you have found $f$, you can verify that the associated measure $\nu$ satisfies your relation $\nu(]a,\infty[\times ]b,\infty[) = e^{-(a+b)^5}.$ There can be only one measure satisfying that relation because the sets of the form $]a,\infty[\times ]b,\infty[$, $a,b\in {\bf R}$, generate the Borel algebra. Hence you are done.

**Edit**

From your computation, we obtain a function $f$ that takes negative values. So it is very dubious that there is actually such a measure. Let us show that **there does not exist any probability measure satisfying your condition**.

Let $A = ]a,\infty[\times ]0,\infty[\,$, $B = ]0,\infty[\times ]a,\infty[\,$. We have
$$\nu(A) = e^{-a^5}, \quad \nu(B) = e^{-a^5}, \quad \nu(A\cap B) = e^{{-(2a)}^5}$$

$$\nu(A\cup B) = \nu(A) + \nu(B) - \nu(A\cap B) = 2e^{-a^5}-e^{-(2a)^5}$$

You can check that this quantity is equal to $1.5705... > 1$  for $a=1/2$, a contradiction.

Comment: As per your answer and my calculations $f=25(b+a)^8e^{-(b+a)^5}-20(b+a)^3e^{-(b+a)^5}$

Comment: So I guess that there is no such probability measure because f is not non-negative for all $a,b>0$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz How do we prove that the function satisfies the properties in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Borel (nonnegative) measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ such that $\mu((a,\infty)\times(b,\infty))=e^{-(a+b)^5}$ for all $a,b\geq0$.
Let $\overline{F}(a,b)=e^{-(a+b)^5 }$. If there were such a measure $\mu$ then
$$\mu((a,a']\times(b,b'])=\overline{F}(a,b)-\overline{F}(a',b)+\overline{F}(a',b')-\overline{F}(a,b')\geq0$$
for all $0\leq a<a'$ and $0\leq b< b'$. In particular
$$\mu((a,a+1/2]\times(b,b+1/2])=e^{-(a+b)^5}-2e^{-(a+b+1/2)^5}+e^{-(a+b+1)^5}\geq0$$
for all $a,b\geq0$. However, as you can check, the  function $\phi(x)=e^{-x^5} - 2e^{-(x+1/2)^5}+ e^{-(x+1)^5}$ is negative near $x=0$.

Similar arguments show that there is no Borel nonnegative measure $\mu_\alpha$  on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ for which $\mu((a,\infty)\times(b,\infty))=e^{-(a+b)^\alpha}$ for $\alpha>1$.

---

If you are considering (sign) Radon measures, then there is one such a measure with density with respect to Lebesgue measure. Uniqueness on Borel sets will follow by Dynkin's $\lambda$-$\pi$ theorem.